# How do I get my village on my phone

Tags: clash-of-clans

My tablet fell off the back of the couch, and so now the screen doesn't work. I don't know how to get my village from my tablet to my phone so I can play

Comment: can you connect your <tablet type unknown> to you computer and sync it or back it up? Can you use any tools (I would recommend some, but I don't know if they will work with <unknown model>

Comment: I dont have a computer and if I did I don't have the cords to plug into the computer

Answer (score 0):

Generally, Clash of Clans syncs to Google Play Games/iCloud, but the user has to enable it. Unless you can get it off your tablet using a computer, there's very little you can do.